# UK AC socket for mounting in enclosure

Tags: power, components, enclosure, hardware

Where can I find a female AC power socket plate/panel and a male computer cable plate/panel which can be installed in an electronics enclosure? I am building a sousvide PID controller which will allow a slow cooker to be plunged into the PID controller. The PID controller will then plug into the wall via a computer power cord. I have no idea what these parts are called or where to find them.

**Edit:**

I am looking for a UK version of this [panel mounted socket](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?sku=2080489&CMP=KNC-GUK-FUK-GEN-SKU-EMC-SCHURTER-CON-MRO&mckv=s8ITwefrL%7Cpcrid%7C13360857549%7Ckword%7C4300.0701%7Cmatch%7Cp%7Cplid%7C)
It must exist somewhere right? Or is there an adapter for it?

thanks,

Comment: Pick the picture that matches your wall from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets). That will tell you the name/number you need.

Answer (score 1):

The search terms you are looking for are "IEC panel mount" for the computer inlet and "13A panel mount" for a UK socket.

Try [RS](http://rswww.com) or similar who have a large range of both items.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I can now find the IEC but can't really find the 13A as all I get are wall mount panels and not ones for electronic enclosures. Will phone RS to get more info. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you see the round sockets? Such as [this one](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/electrical-sockets/5000459/). Alternatively look for Berker sockets for use in caravans etc.

Comment: thanks for the help but i want a 13a socket similar to this IEC one which can be fitted into an enclosure. http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/iec-connectors/2043879/